# Absolute minimal way to link AWS API Gateway to container image

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-api-gateway

I have a docker image uploaded ECR that provides a single page web app. I would like to make an API Gateway endpoint that starts a new instance based on that image, and then maps port 443 (or 80) to container port 7894 (specified by app in the image).

Sketch of ideal architecture:

- Running EC2 instance based off my ECR image
- API Gateway with single GET endpoint mapping.

That is, I want something as close as possible to what I starting the image via

```sh
docker run -p 80:7894 my_app:latest
```

and navigating to `http://localhost`.

I only ever want at most one of these running (not a hard requirement, just saying I don't feel I need a load balancer), and I have a preference for "less" security given there's security in the app and I'm literally the only person who will be using this. That is, I'd be very happy if I could

1. start a new container
2. directly expose port 7894 of that to the internet

What is the absolute minimal set of resources I need to set up to make this happen?

I've tried a few approaches based on Fargate, but these all end up requiring a number of extra networking and load balancing steps (VPC/subnets, ALB/NLB/CloudMap, ...) that seem unnecessary.

Comment: Check out AWS App Runner. That could fit your use case quite well.

Comment: Yes, App Runner is exactly what I was looking for!! Thank you. If you make that an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS offers numerous way to run containers. At the time of writing the probably easiest way for use case is to use [AWS App Runner](https://aws.amazon.com/apprunner/). App Runner allows you to provide a Docker image and will deploy that including auto scaling and load balancing without you to need to worry about all the heavy lifting. Instead you'll directly get a HTTP endpoint you can reach your app at and that's it.

Comment: Like I said already, this is a huge help. I've used Fargate for analytics cron jobs before, but never tried to connect one to the outside world. It seems like App Runner fills the gap between container and HTTP endpoint that otherwise requires a lot more investment for Fargate or EC2 directly.